# Analyic geometry

Tags: geometry

I'm so lost,

Two vertices of an isosceles triangle are (1,5) & (6,3). Find a third vertex and show that two of the three side lengths are equal.

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: Two hints. You could think about points on the perpendicular bisector of the segment given, or points on a circle whose radius in the segment given. Draw pictures before you try the algebra.

Comment: An isosceles triangle is a triangle with (at least) two equal sides. Try sketching first, you may get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

An isosceles triangle is a triangle with (at least) two equal sides.

Part1: Finding the third vertex:

Given points $A$, $B$
Draw $A$, $B$ and connect them.

We need to draw AC but we don't know where is $C$, let's find it.

We know that there exists a line $BC$ and that the line $MA$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

Draw a line parallel to X-axis up to $M(6,5).

We know $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

We need to know the distance between $M$ and $C$. To do that, we calculate BM = $B_X-A_X=2$

Since $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$, the length of $MC=2$.

This gives us the point $C$ to be at (6,7).

Now we know all three points that define the triangle.

Part2: Use the Pythagorean theorem to find the lengths $AB$ and $AC$, you will find them to be equal to $sqrt{29}.

[image]